# bittorrent-dht bruteforce hash discovery questions

Tags: node.js, bittorrent, dht

So, I am new to node.js, I picked it up out of necessity to use bittorrent-dht which seems to have all I need for my idea.

My idea is basically to generate random hex strings, and do a lookup on the DHT, keep the ones with enough peers, to later examine in a proper torrent client (in my case I use Tixati).

To that effect I wrote the following bit of code, it is not elegant, I am new to node.js, keep that in mind...

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

function rand_string(n) {
    if (n <= 0) {
            return '';
        }
        var rs = '';
        try {
            rs = crypto.randomBytes(n);
        rs = rs.toString('hex').slice(0,n);
            /* note: could do this non-blocking, but still might fail */
        }
        catch(ex) {
        console.log("cannot genhash");    
    }
        return rs;
}

const min_peers = 100;
var DHT = require('bittorrent-dht');
var dht = new DHT();
var hash = [];
var abort_lookup_0;
var abort_lookup_1;
var abort_lookup_2;
var abort_lookup_3;
var peers = [];
dht.listen(63112, function() {
    console.log('DHT started');
    //
    hash[0] = rand_string(40);
    peers[0] = 0;
    abort_lookup_0 = dht.lookup(hash[0]);
    //
    hash[1] = rand_string(40);
    peers[1] = 0;
    abort_lookup_1 = dht.lookup(hash[1]);
    //
    hash[2] = rand_string(40);
        peers[2] = 0;
        abort_lookup_2 = dht.lookup(hash[2]);
    //
    hash[3] = rand_string(40);
        peers[3] = 0;
        abort_lookup_3 = dht.lookup(hash[3]);
});

// this is horrible but it will probably save headaches with loops
dht.on('peer', function (peer, infoHash, from) {
    if (infoHash.toString('hex') == hash[0]) peers[0]++;
    if (infoHash.toString('hex') == hash[1]) peers[1]++;
    if (infoHash.toString('hex') == hash[2]) peers[2]++;
    if (infoHash.toString('hex') == hash[3]) peers[3]++;
    //
    if (peers[0] > min_peers) {
        abort_lookup_0();
        console.log(hash[0]);
        peers[0] = 0;
        hash[0] = rand_string(40);
        abort_lookup_0 = dht.lookup(hash[0]);
    }
    //
    if (peers[1] > min_peers) {
        abort_lookup_1();
        console.log(hash[1]);
        peers[1] = 0;
        hash[1] = rand_string(40);
        abort_lookup_1 = dht.lookup(hash[1]);
    }
    //
    if (peers[2] > min_peers) {
                abort_lookup_2();
                console.log(hash[2]);
                peers[2] = 0;
                hash[2] = rand_string(40);
                abort_lookup_2 = dht.lookup(hash[2]);
        }
    //
    if (peers[3] > min_peers) {
                abort_lookup_3();
                console.log(hash[3]);
                peers[3] = 0;
                hash[3] = rand_string(40);
                abort_lookup_3 = dht.lookup(hash[3]);
        }
})  

function failedHash() {
    abort_lookup_0();
    hash[0] = rand_string(40);
    peers[0] = 0;
    abort_lookup_0 = dht.lookup(hash[0]);
    //
    abort_lookup_1();
    hash[1] = rand_string(40);
    peers[1] = 0;
    abort_lookup_1 = dht.lookup(hash[1]);
    //
        abort_lookup_2();
        hash[2] = rand_string(40);
        peers[2] = 0;
        abort_lookup_2 = dht.lookup(hash[2]);
    //
        abort_lookup_3();
        hash[3] = rand_string(40);
        peers[3] = 0;
        abort_lookup_3 = dht.lookup(hash[3]);
}

setInterval(failedHash, 15000);
```

So, I am running 4 different lookups and keeping the ones with > 100 peers. Obviously this rarely turns up anything, for now... If I lower my expectations to say 50 peers or below, I obviously get more hits, but feeding the hashes into Tixati lead to either it not finding peers or finding peers but failing to connect to them (timeout).

My questions are as follows:

- Is this code sane ? I don't mean is it elegant, but are there really obvious bugs or things I am overlooking ?
- Why does my torrent client fail to connect to the peers for the hashes that do seem to have peers ? (note: my torrent client is perfectly functional etc...); am I bumping into some odd private/blocking peers ?
- What is a sane minimum number of peers to search for ?

I'll leave this running on my raspberry for now, but I don't expect much; or at least not before a long time...

Comment: Your method is flawed. The chance to generate a 160 bit random number that is a real info_hash is so infinitesimal that it's impossible. The hits you see is from malicious nodes that gives you bogus peers.

Comment: I know the odds are not great, but this why I am filtering the "noise" by setting a minimum number of peers.

Answer (score 1):

> the odds are not great

This is an understatement. Merely incrementing a cpu register from 0 to 2¹⁶⁰-1 would [require more energy than it takes to boil all of earth's oceans](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/257336).

Brute force enumeration of DHT keys is not possible with technology currently available to mankind.

Currently the only way to gather infohashes from the DHT is by listening for incoming requests. This is fairly inefficient and noisy and is not something one would want to do on a regular end user machine. On a server, preferably with multiple IP addresses you could use [my implementation](https://github.com/the8472/mldht) which does all the necessary heavy lifting.